# how to set the color for all the content pages in master page

Tags: asp.net, css

i have 6 content place  holder in my master page. 
i need   to set the  background color [body] for  all my  content place holder in my master page  to    light  gold  color.  so  that   all my  content page  wil  content  this  color[body]

how  do    do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way would be css:

```
body {
    background: #FFD700;
}
```

As an alternative to Dave's solution, you could have a div at the top level inside your placeholders:

```
<asp:Content ID="first" ContentPlaceHolderID="_firstContainer" runat="server">
    <div class='content'>
        // do presentation
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

With css:

```
.content{
    background: #FFD700;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap each content placeholder in a `div` in the master page then style each `div` so that the background colour is light gold.

```
<div class="goldcontent">
    <asp:ContentPlaceholder ID="Content1" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceholder>
</div>

<%-- other controls --%>

<div class="goldcontent">
    <asp:ContentPlaceholder ID="Content2" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceholder>
</div>

<%-- etc --%>
```

Then in your css file

```
div .goldcontent
{
    background-color: # FFD700;
}
```